# Specifying xDomain for discreteBarChart in nvd3 makes the chart improper

Tags: d3.js, graph, nvd3.js

When I try to plot discreteBarChart without specifying xDomain, following is the output: [Image of the Good graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjWdH.png)

Whereas when I plot discreteBarChart with specifying xDomain, following is the output: [Image of the Bad graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ysOc.png)

Following is the code I used to specify chart options:

```
       chart: {
                type: "discreteBarChart",
                height: 350,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 50,
                    left: 65
                },
                x: function(d){ return d['x']; },
                y: function(d){ return d['y']; },

                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel:  xAxisLabel,                        
                    showMaxMin: false,
                    axisLabelDistance: 2
                },

                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: yAxisLabel,                        
                    axisLabelDistance: 0,
                },
                legend: {margin: {top: 5}},
                xDomain:[xLowerLimit,xUpperLimit] /* This is where the problem is */
            },
            title: {
                enable :true,
                text: chartTitle
            }
```

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting such a messed up discreteBarChart plot when I specify the xDomain?

I am using nvd3 1.8.5.

I found this link (https_://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/264) which handles a similar problem for linePlusBarChart. The solution mentioned in that link is to edit the nvd3 source file with 'xDomain' related codes. In order to try the same, I looked at the source code, but found out that xDomain part for discreteBarChart to be good for my eyes.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr/jsfiddle? Not sure what you're trying to achieve with the xDomain?

Answer (score 0):

```
  chart: {
            type: "discreteBarChart",
            height: 350,
            margin : {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 50,
                left: 65
            },
            x: function(d){ return d['x']; },
            y: function(d){ return d['y']; },

            xAxis: {
                axisLabel:  xAxisLabel,                        
                showMaxMin: false,
                axisLabelDistance: 2
            },

            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: yAxisLabel,                        
                axisLabelDistance: 0,
            },
            legend: {margin: {top: 5}},
            forceX: [xLowerLimit,xUpperLimit]
        },
        title: {
            enable :true,
            text: chartTitle
        }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16436533)

Comment: @garyh Please be careful when reviewing in the LQPRQ! This post doesn't even contain a link.